# Connecting to proxmox web GUI via hamachi

Tags: proxmox, hamachi

I have a server with multiple network adaptors. I have installed proxmox, and hamachi on that. I want to be able to access the web GUI through hamachi as I am not able to port forward or have both the server and laptop on the same network. My server IP on hamachi is 25.54.34.60. I want to be able to access the web-GUI, which is accessible on 1.2.3.4:8006 (example ip) from the hamachi IP. I have no idea how to do this. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A) Preliminary steps to follow if you're not using the Enterprise version of Proxmox:

1. Fix your repository so that the enterprise repository is disabled (commented out) and such that the `sources.list` contains the correct URL ([see information here](https://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Package_Repositories))
2. While you're in there, you might as well do this if you're not on enterprise: https://johnscs.com/remove-proxmox51-subscription-notice/
3. Sing up for a Hamachi account: https://secure.logmein.com/welcome/hamachi/vpn/default.aspx

B) Hamachi installation and setup:

1. Go to [this page and follow the "**Task One**" steps](https://lmibinarieslive.blob.core.windows.net/linux/index.html#/linux). For steps 1 & 2, see this:
   [image: steps 1 and 2]
2. Continue on to "**Task Two**" and when you get into the `snapd` installation process, see [Debian instructions here](https://snapcraft.io/docs/installing-snap-on-debian) and *be sure* to reload your terminal to get `$PATH` reloaded (if you're on the web interface Shell, reload browser).

C) Accept the pending join request if you've set it to require admin acceptation from Hamachi:

1. Notice pending join request:

   [image: 1]
2. Accept it:

   [image: 2]

You're done!